# Locally paging on Extjs 5 store of type ajax

Tags: extjs, store, paging, extjs5

I am working on an app where loading all data from the beginning is not really an inconvenient.

I am getting json data from a server through Ajax, and my store for doing that is pretty simple:

```
Ext.define('MODIFE.store.CentroBeneficio', {
    extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires : [
        'MODIFE.model.CentroBeneficio'
    ],
    storeId : 'CentroBeneficio',
    model   : 'MODIFE.model.CentroBeneficio',
    page-size: 10,
    proxy   :{
        //type: 'memory',
        type: 'ajax',
        enablePaging: true,
        url: 'http://'+MODIFE.Global.ip+'/CentroBeneficio/GetCentroBeneficios'
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

This is my model:

```
Ext.define('MODIFE.model.CentroBeneficio', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    storeId: 'CentroBeneficio',
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: [
        {name:'IdCentroBeneficio', type:'int'},
        {name:'CompaniaCodigo', type:'int'},
        {name:'codigo', type:'string'},
        {name:'description', type:'string'},
        {name:'complete_description', type:'string', convert : function(v, record) {return record.data.codigo+' - '+record.data.description;}},
        {name:'status', type:'int', convert : function(v, record) {return (record.data.status == 1) ? 'Activo' : 'Inactivo';}},
        {name:'name_compania', type:'string'},
        {name:'pais', type:'string'},
        {name:'IdPais', type:'int'}

    ]
});
```

**What I would like to achieve is paging the already loaded data.** I tried specifying the type to 'memory' which didn't load anything as well as 'pagingmemory', wich caused the browser to die (I don't know why).

I have already the paging bar set up on my view:

```
    {
            xtype: 'grid',
            id: 'centroBeneficioGrid',
            title: getLabelByKey('CentroBeneficio_SearchGridTitle_Listado'),
            store: 'CentroBeneficio',
            columns: [
                { text: getLabelByKey('CentroBeneficio_SearchColumnGrid_Pais'),  dataIndex: 'pais', flex: 2},
                { text: getLabelByKey('CentroBeneficio_SearchColumnGrid_Company'), dataIndex: 'name_compania', flex: 3},
                { text: getLabelByKey('CentroBeneficio_SearchColumnGrid_CentroBeneficio'), dataIndex: 'codigo', flex: 2},
                { text: getLabelByKey('CentroBeneficio_SearchColumnGrid_Descripcion'), dataIndex: 'description', flex: 4},
                { text: getLabelByKey('CentroBeneficio_SearchColumnGrid_Estatus'), dataIndex: 'status', flex: 2}
            ],
            listeners: {
                itemdblclick: 'CBSelectedGrid'
            },
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                store: 'CentroBeneficio',
                dock: 'bottom',
                displayInfo: true
            }],
        }
```

It shows up correctly but it just loads all data on the first page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check (using Firebug or something) if paging parameters are added to the URL? Does your server recognise and honour them?

Comment: Yes, they are passed as params, but what I am trying to achieve is to page the already loaded records, so no server intervention is longer needed on this process after the first load of data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Paging of already loaded data is achieved with `Ext.data.proxy.Memory` configured with [`enablePaging: true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory-cfg-enablePaging). So what you need is to use two stores:

1. "Remote" store to merely load data from the server side;
2. Local paging store configured with memory proxy. The data will be loaded from the remote store once it loads itself:

```js
pagingStore.getProxy().setData(remoteStore.getRange());
pagingStore.load();
```

Full working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pim

Comment: Yes, the pagination works with this configuration. The problem is, that the local pagination is applied before sorting and filtering. If you sort anything in your fiddle, it will sort only the current page. I am currently trying to find a solution to this problem, sadly, no luck so far.

Comment: I found the solution in a [Sencha forum thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?305119-Grid-Filter-on-Local-Paging). To sort and filter the locally paginated data correctly `remoteSort` and `remoteFilter` store configuration has to be set to filter and sort the data by the proxy.