# Pagging is working with static but not for dynamic data

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I am trying to load the grid with json data and Pagging in bottom bar.

My paging is loading but not working. With same this is working for static data.

Here is my fiddle with static data, [Fiddle_Static](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25vf)
Here is my fiddle with static data, [Fiddle Dynamic](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25u6)
Here is my code.

```
var ItemsPerPage = 3;

Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'Store',
        proxy :{
        enablePaging: true,
        type:'ajax',
        url: 'data1.json',
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            rootProperty:"root"
        }
    },
    pageSize: ItemsPerPage,
    autoLoad:true,
    fields: ['Surname','Name','RollNo']
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Student',
    store:Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Store'),

    columns:
[
   { text : 'SName' , dataIndex: 'Surname' ,width : 100},
   { text : 'Name' ,  dataIndex: 'Name' ,width : 100},
   { text : 'RNum' ,  dataIndex: 'RollNo' ,width : 100}
],
    width: 340,
    height:250,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype:'pagingtoolbar',
        store:'Store',
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo:true
        }],
    renderTo: document.body
});
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: enablePaging is a property of Ext.data.proxy.Memory, not Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.  Look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082315/locally-paging-on-extjs-5-store-of-type-ajax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locally paging on Extjs 5 store of type ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082315/locally-paging-on-extjs-5-store-of-type-ajax)

Answer (score 2):

Paging against an external data source requires the server to only deliver the requested records.

When the first page is loaded into the grid, the store sends to the server the request:

```
data1.json?page=1&start=0&limit=3
```

and expects the server to answer with

```
success:true,
total:27,
data:[{Id:0},{Id:1},{Id:2}] (<-- three items only!)
```

When the user wants to see page 2, the client then sends to the server the request:

```
data1.json?page=2&start=3&limit=3
```

and expects the answer

```
success:true,
total:27,
data:[{Id:3},{Id:4},{Id:5}] (<-- three items only!)
```

and so on.

Your data source right now is returning all items, although the client asked for the first three only.

To get a dynamic data source in fiddle, you have to check "Dynamic data source" at the top of data1.json, and then the header changes to:

```
function(params, req, Fiddle) {
```

[image]

Now you can fill in the function body, e.g. quick and dirty with

```
if(params.page==1)
return {"total":12, "root" : [{
   "Surname": "lisa",
   "Name":"King",
   "RollNo": 1
  },
  {
   "Surname": "John",
   "Name":"Lever",
   "RollNo": 2
  },
  {
   "Surname": "Lee",
   "Name":"Dev",
   "RollNo": 3
  }]};
else if(params.page == 2) 
...
```

How to do it in your final project depends on how your backend looks like.

Comment: Yes, completely understand what request need to send to server and what to get. Thanks for explanation. But here I coul'nt found how to put these code in my ajax.

Comment: @David I have amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpfull

Answer (score -1):

I Think that´s not working cause the sum of `width`at the lines 
`{ text : 'SName' , dataIndex: 'Surname' ,width : 100},` 
isnt the same as your widht of the table `width: 340,`

Comment: How does even it is related. Can you check in fiddler what are you saying.

Comment: I checked. I´ve changed `width: 340,` to `width: 600,` and `{ text : 'SName' , dataIndex: 'Surname' ,width : 100},` to `{ text : 'SName' , dataIndex: 'Surname' ,width : 200},` ( for each) ... and it worked for me.

Comment: Can you please share the fiddler. I changed too. No luck dude

Comment: That is what I am trying to tell you is "Paging is not working." Only two record should display.

Comment: misunderstood you. sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153448/discussion-between-david-and-kevin-liss).